# ASP.NET Core Request / Response logging middleware

Tags: c#, logging, memory-optimization, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am looking for feedbacks about my ASP.NET Core Request / Response logging middleware, in particular in ways to lower the memory footprint and string allocations:

```
public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware> _logger;
    private readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager _recyclableMemoryStreamManager;
    private const int ReadChunkBufferLength = 4096;

    public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
        _recyclableMemoryStreamManager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var requestProfilerModel = new RequestProfilerModel
        {
            RequestTime = new DateTimeOffset(),
            Context = context,
            Request = await FormatRequestAsync(context)
        };

        var originalBody = context.Response.Body;

        using (var newResponseBody = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = newResponseBody;

            await _next(context);

            newResponseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            await newResponseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBody);

            newResponseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            requestProfilerModel.Response = await FormatResponseAsync(context, newResponseBody);
            requestProfilerModel.ResponseTime = new DateTimeOffset();

            _logger.LogInformation(requestProfilerModel.Request);
            _logger.LogInformation(requestProfilerModel.Response);
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> FormatResponseAsync(HttpContext context, Stream newResponseBody)
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        var response = context.Response;

        return $"Http Response Information: {Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"Schema: {request.Scheme} {Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"Host: {request.Host} {Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"Path: {request.Path} {Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"QueryString: {request.QueryString} {Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"Headers: {Environment.NewLine}" + FormatHeaders(response.Headers) +
                $"StatusCode: {response.StatusCode} {Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"Response Body: {await ReadStreamInChunksAsync(newResponseBody)}";
    }

    private async Task<string> FormatRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = context.Request;

        return $"Http Request Information: {Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"Schema:{request.Scheme} {Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"Host: {request.Host} {Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"Path: {request.Path} {Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"QueryString: {request.QueryString} {Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $"Headers: {Environment.NewLine}" + FormatHeaders(request.Headers) +
                    $"Request Body: {await GetRequestBodyAsync(request)}";
    }

    private string FormatHeaders(IHeaderDictionary headers)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var (key, value) in headers)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine($"- {key}: {value}");
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public async Task<string> GetRequestBodyAsync(HttpRequest request)
    {
        request.EnableBuffering();
        request.EnableRewind();
        using (var stream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream())
        {
            await request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
            request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return await ReadStreamInChunksAsync(stream);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<string> ReadStreamInChunksAsync(Stream stream)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string result;

        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var readChunk = new char[ReadChunkBufferLength];
            int readChunkLength;
            //do while: is useful for the last iteration in case readChunkLength < chunkLength
            do
            {
                readChunkLength = await streamReader.ReadBlockAsync(readChunk, 0, ReadChunkBufferLength);
                await stringWriter.WriteAsync(readChunk, 0, readChunkLength);
            } while (readChunkLength > 0);

            result = stringWriter.ToString();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using [Factory-based middleware](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/extensibility?view=aspnetcore-2.2) instead of the by-convention method that you share here. You would then be able to have scoped DI.

For string concatenation, consider using a `StringBuilder` instead of the plus-operator everywhere. I can see you use it in some places, but that string concatenation with interpolation "looks" costly. Refer to the [remarks section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) to see if the `StringBuilder` is a good choice for your use-case.

Experiment with `ReadChunkBufferLength` and consider making it a configurable value with a sane default. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780316/optimal-buffer-size-for-response-stream-of-httpwebresponse) might provide some insight.

Comment: String concatenation with `+` only matters in loops. Here it doesn't make any difference and OP is already using `StringBuilder` with a loop. What's ugly are the new-lines. `string.Join` would be an option too.

Comment: @t3chb0t btw, nothing can be improved through `Span<T>`?

Comment: @EhouarnPerret `Span<T>` is for reading and creating `string` _views_ to avoid copying it, you are only creating `string`s and writing so I don't thing it could help.

Comment: @t3chb0t okay makes sense, thanks for the clarifications!